# Mechanical Turk - Bonus groups of workers

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is it possible to assign a bonus to a list of workers, without an assignment ID? 
Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot!
Gabriella

Answer (score 1):

No. BonusWorker requires an assignment ID.

As an alternative, you could give the workers you want to bonus a certain qualification, then create a HIT just for them that requires that qualification.